# Can't install WWW:Curl on new Ubuntu 16.04 server

Tags: perl, curl

I'm trying to work out why I can't install **WWW::Curl** on my new server. I've done:

`apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev`

...and then:

`cpanm WWW::Curl`

I then get an error after a while. The log looks like:

```
cpanm (App::cpanminus) 1.7040 on perl 5.022001 built for x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi
Work directory is /root/.cpanm/work/1496041822.25089
You have make /usr/bin/make
You have LWP 6.15
You have /bin/tar: tar (GNU tar) 1.28
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by John Gilmore and Jay Fenlason.
You have /usr/bin/unzip
Searching WWW::Curl () on cpanmetadb ...
--> Working on WWW::Curl
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/S/SZ/SZBALINT/WWW-Curl-4.17.tar.gz
-> OK
Unpacking WWW-Curl-4.17.tar.gz
Entering WWW-Curl-4.17
Checking configure dependencies from META.yml
Checking if you have ExtUtils::MakeMaker 6.58 ... Yes (7.04_01)
Configuring WWW-Curl-4.17
Running Makefile.PL
Locating required external dependency bin:curl-config... found at /usr/bin/curl-config.
The version is libcurl 7.47.0
Found curl.h in /usr/include/curl/curl.h
Building curlopt-constants.c for your libcurl version
Building Easy.pm constants for your libcurl version
Building Share.pm constants for your libcurl version
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Generating a Unix-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for WWW::Curl
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
-> OK
Checking dependencies from MYMETA.json ...
Checking if you have ExtUtils::MakeMaker 0 ... Yes (7.04_01)
Building and testing WWW-Curl-4.17
cp lib/WWW/Curl/Easy.pm blib/lib/WWW/Curl/Easy.pm
cp lib/WWW/Curl/Form.pm blib/lib/WWW/Curl/Form.pm
cp lib/WWW/Curl.pm blib/lib/WWW/Curl.pm
cp lib/WWW/Curl/Multi.pm blib/lib/WWW/Curl/Multi.pm
cp lib/WWW/Curl/Share.pm blib/lib/WWW/Curl/Share.pm
Running Mkbootstrap for WWW::Curl ()
chmod 644 "Curl.bs"
"/usr/bin/perl" "-Iinc" "/usr/share/perl/5.22/ExtUtils/xsubpp"  -typemap "/usr/share/perl/5.22/ExtUtils/typemap" -typemap "typemap"  Curl.xs > Curl.xsc && mv Curl.xsc Curl.c
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -c  -I/usr/include -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -DDEBIAN -fwrapv -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -I/usr/local/include -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -O2 -g   -DVERSION=\"4.17\" -DXS_VERSION=\"4.17\" -fPIC "-I/u$
In file included from Curl.xs:574:0:
curlopt-constants.c: In function âconstantâ:
curlopt-constants.c:2033:44: warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion [-Woverflow]
             if (strEQ(name, "ANY")) return CURLAUTH_ANY;
                                            ^
curlopt-constants.c:2034:48: warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion [-Woverflow]
             if (strEQ(name, "ANYSAFE")) return CURLAUTH_ANYSAFE;
                                                ^
rm -f blib/arch/auto/WWW/Curl/Curl.so
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc  -shared -L/usr/local/lib -fstack-protector-strong Curl.o  -o blib/arch/auto/WWW/Curl/Curl.so      \
   -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lcurl   \

chmod 755 blib/arch/auto/WWW/Curl/Curl.so
"/usr/bin/perl" "-Iinc" -MExtUtils::Command::MM -e 'cp_nonempty' -- Curl.bs blib/arch/auto/WWW/Curl/Curl.bs 644
Manifying 1 pod document
Running Mkbootstrap for WWW::Curl ()
chmod 644 "Curl.bs"
PERL_DL_NONLAZY=1 "/usr/bin/perl" "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-MTest::Harness" "-e" "undef *Test::Harness::Switches; test_harness(0, 'inc', 'blib/lib', 'blib/arch')" t/*.t
t/00constants.t ........... ok

#   Failed test 'Got 1 or more cookies'
#   at t/01basic.t line 57.
# Looks like you failed 1 test of 19.
t/01basic.t ...............
Dubious, test returned 1 (wstat 256, 0x100)
Failed 1/19 subtests
t/02callbacks.t ........... ok
t/04abort-test.t .......... ok
t/05progress.t ............ ok
t/06http-post.t ........... skipped: Not performing http POST/upload tests
t/07ftp-upload.t .......... skipped: Not performing ftp upload tests
t/08ssl.t ................. ok
t/09times.t ............... ok
t/10errbuf.t .............. ok
t/13slowleak.t ............ skipped: Not performing slow leakage regression test
t/14duphandle.t ........... ok
t/15duphandle-callback.t .. ok
t/16formpost.t ............ skipped: Not performing POST
t/17slist.t ............... skipped: Not performing printenv cgi tests
t/18twinhandles.t ......... ok
t/19multi.t ............... ok
t/20undefined_subs.t ...... ok
t/21write-to-scalar.t ..... ok
t/meta.t .................. skipped: Test::CPAN::Meta required for testing META.yml
t/pod-coverage.t .......... skipped: Test::Pod::Coverage 1.04 required for testing POD coverage
t/pod.t ................... skipped: Test::Pod 1.14 required for testing POD

Test Summary Report
-------------------
t/01basic.t             (Wstat: 256 Tests: 19 Failed: 1)
  Failed test:  19
  Non-zero exit status: 1
Files=22, Tests=816, 21 wallclock secs ( 0.26 usr  0.07 sys +  1.40 cusr  0.48 csys =  2.21 CPU)
Result: FAIL
Failed 1/22 test programs. 1/816 subtests failed.
Makefile:936: recipe for target 'test_dynamic' failed
make: *** [test_dynamic] Error 255
-> FAIL Installing WWW::Curl failed. See /root/.cpanm/work/1496041822.25089/build.log for details. Retry with --force to force install it.
```

If I run `curl --version` from CLI, I get a result, so it must be installed.

I'm not really sure what else to try. Anyone got any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Typically, I now found the answer! I found this post:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42290344/failed-during-install-wwwcurleasy-in-cpan
```

So running this:

```
apt-get install libwww-curl-perl
```

...and it has now installed, and appears to be working fine :)

Comment: those are not equal...
your first version is the installation via CPAN (without involving APT)

the second one is using the package manager from Ubuntu.

For your case this might be irrelevant, for others however this could lead to problems.

Comment: Installing from official repos is usually a smart plan unless you need the absolute latest code.

Comment: @DennisNolte - I appreciate that. However, for me it worked - so I just wanted to share my solution in case anyone else had the same problem.